# Prometheus filter query result using lables in result

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to build an API which can take inputs and filter data based on the inputs that i provide. 
Say my input is going to be something like ,

```
{
 "node":"IPAddress:9100",
 "cpu":"0"
}
```

And my prometheus query is (100 - 100*node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"})/node_cpu_seconds_total .
This gives me the cpu usage of all the targets.

I want to filter out the data relevant to the target, which i give as node to my wrapper API. So is there any function or way where i can always put a filter on the query result and get the data from prometheus.

For example, i want to do something like

```
((100 - 100*node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"})/node_cpu_seconds_total){instance="IPAddress:9100"}
```

So that i get the CPU usage for my node only. I know we can enter instance details as ,

```
node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance="prometheus"}
```

But for different queries, i have to place the filter that i give to my api at different positions, hence, if there is a way to filter once i get my result at the end, it would suffice my requirement.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this by using the and operator. my query now looks like,

```
((100 - 100*node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"})/node_cpu_seconds_total) and ({instance="localhost:9100"})
```

This is filtering out my data with the filter that i give at the end.